# How to check if a specific file exist and which exit code to use?

Tags: vbscript, file-exists

I have a deployment of 6 tasks and I want to make sure that step #2 will not be processed if step #1 failed. Similarly, subsequent tasks should only be processed if the previous ones were successful.

To do this, I have to run a vb script before installation or uninstallation on each step. I'm trying to use a script (not from me) that I have modified for pre-uninstallation of software and also post-installation of the software.

Pre-uninstallation: The script will look if the specified "exe" exists on the server and, if so, then it will run the `msiuninstall <application_name>`.

If the uninstallation is successful, the post-installation script will check if the "exe" file exists again on the server, and it shouldn't find it (because it was deleted by the uninstallation), then it will return an exit code of `success` and proceed to run the next process.

Here an example:

1. Uninstall "Software#1" with msiuninstall Software#1.exe
   command
2. Uninstall "Software#2" with msiuninstall Software#2.exe
   command
3. Install "Software #3"with an .exe extension
4. Re install "Software #2" with an .msi extension
5. Re install "Software #1" with a .msi extension.
6. Send email to confirm the deployment is successful

At the end, Step 6 should send an email to confirm that the 6 steps of the deployment was completed without errors. How do I go about this?

This is the script I'm working with:

'This script will look if an .exe file exist for a specific application.
'==========================================================================================

```
 path = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
 set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Enterprise\EnterpriseWS\web.config")= True then
   exitCode = 0
else
   exitCode = 1
```

End If

```
Wscript.Quit exitCode
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the file name in quotes:

```
If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Enterprise\EnterpriseWS\web.config") = True Then
```

Comment: I have tried and got the error :
Line 1
Char 1
Error: Subscript out of range
Code: 800A0009
Microsoft VBScript runtime error

path = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
 set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Enterprise\EnterpriseWS\web.config")= True then
   exitCode = 0
else
   exitCode = 1
End If
Wscript.Quit exitCode

Comment: Can you show us the whole script? The error is probably because you didn't pass in a path on the command line when you called the script.